# C++11 extern complex Container and Container initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, extern, initialization-vector

When we want to have an exported variable (both in C and C++) we need to:

- declare the variable as extern in an hpp header file (i.e. extern int x;)

- initialize the variable in a cpp file (i.e.: int x = 0).

However, I have found difficulties with containers and I am receiving messages like "the variable is declared multiple times" and so forth.

For example:

hpp file:

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> VectorOfPairs_t;
export VectorOfPairs_t vectorOfPairs;
```

cpp file:

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> myPair;
myPair = std::make_pair("hello", "world");
vectorOfPairs.push_back( myPair ); // All this is just a hack
                                   // to initialize the container...
```

main.cpp (or other cpp):

```
use of vectorOfPairs accordingly to my requirements
```

But, as I have mentioned, this is not compiling.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You say `extern` but you write `export` in your code.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks very much for your answer. But you have to recognize that I deserve an award to stupidity after reviewing that code many times.
Other than that, I did not receive any more the error of "multiple declarations", but I receive another one: **"undefined reference to vectorOfPairs"**. I guess this should be related to some required (?) initialization. Any advice on this will be very much appreciated!

Comment: have you included `hpp` file into `cpp` file?

Comment: You seem to be missing the "initialize the variable in a cpp file (i.e.: int x = 0)." part. `vectorOfPairs` is never thus defined. In one .cpp file, write `VectorOfPairs_t vectorOfPairs;` or perhaps `VectorOfPairs_t vectorOfPairs{{"hello", "world"}};`